# Quantum vs. Classical Ising model and the Bohr van Leeuwen Theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, ising-model, ferromagnetism

The classical Ising model is [often described](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) as a simplistic model for ferromagnetism, and the [Bohr-Van Leeuwen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Van_Leeuwen_theorem) is understood to preclude classical physics origins of magnetization in matter.

So if one tries to understand the underlying physics from which the Ising model emerges as a fair description of matter, the relevant degrees of freedom are the electronic (or atomic) moments that arise from quantum mechanical origin (spin and angular momentum number). So this means the "classical" Ising model is also quantum.

Therefor my question is, what make the classical Ising model classical? And how come considering a classical model sees to violate the Bohr-Van Leeuwen theorem?

Answer (score 0):

*Classical* Ising model is about a system with discrete states. So this model is actually quantum. And that was said in the answer proposed by Yvan Velenik in his comment.

But I still want to focus on one nuance. To see the difference between *classical* and *quantum* Ising models, just look at their Hamiltonians. Hamiltonian of the *classical* model
$$
\hat{H}_c = -\sum_{j,k} J_{j,k}\hat{\sigma}_j^z\hat{\sigma}_k^z
$$
does not contain non-commuting operators while Hamiltonian of the *quantum* model
$$
\hat{H}_q = -\sum_{j,k} J_{j,k}\hat{\sigma}_j^z\hat{\sigma}_k^z - h \sum_j \hat{\sigma}_j^x
$$
does. In this respect, one model is classical, and the other is quantum.

Comment: Hamiltonian in classical model is still an operator? Are $\hat{}$ signs above $\sigma$ indicates they are operator ? I mean, usually we take $\sigma = \{-1,+1\}$ in classical ising model, means we take that as scalars usually. Right ?

Comment: @curious_mind $\sigma_j = \pm 1$ are the eigenvalues of the operators $\hat{\sigma}^z_j$. In the case where there are no non-commuting operators in the Hamiltonian, one can replace the operators with their eigenvalues and obtain the energies of the configurations corresponding to different sets of $\sigma_j$.